# Format DATETIME column in the CREATE TABLE clause with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, datetime-format, create-table

I'm working in MYSQL database and trying set the format in DATETIME column in the creation table moment. I'm searching something similar to this:

**`select DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,'%d-%c-%Y --- HH:MM:SS');`**

But applied on CREATE TABLE something like this:

**`CREATE TABLE name_t1 (name_col VARCHAR(30), start_day DATE ####)`**

"####" should be the format modifier

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: The `datetime` is stored using an internal format.  You can convert it to and from a string using `format()` and `date_format()`.

Comment: Decided what you want. `Date` or `datetime`. And simply create it and use it. And read the manual

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544484/changing-format-date-mysql.  I've seen some business intelligence and database packages that can do something like what you want, but I don't think MySQL has that capability.  You may be able to change the default print format for all DATE and DATETIME using my.cnf/my.ini files.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-instance-options-file.html