# Format a date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

To get a date I can do:

```
select date(now())
```

And it will give me:

```
2018-11-30
```

How would I format it as:

```
YYYYMMDD
```

So it gives me:

```
20181130
```

Is there a better way than:

```
select replace(date(now()), '-','')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing format date MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544484/changing-format-date-mysql)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
```

Manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format